# change coordinate lat and long to andress

Tags: java, android, google-maps, coordinates

how to change the coordinate lat and long that we get and make it to andress.
i'am learning from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/.

thank you so much :)

mainactivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnShowLocation;

// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

   // show location button click event
   btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {        
           // create class object
           gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

           // check if GPS enabled     
           if(gps.canGetLocation()){

               double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
               double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

               // \n is for new line
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
           }else{
               // can't get location
               // GPS or Network is not enabled
               // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
               gps.showSettingsAlert();
           }

       }
   });
 }

}
```

GPStracker.java

```
package unai.skripsi.test;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
 }

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this:

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
```

Comment: how to implementation to my coding bro @PiyushGupta ?
i'am still beginner for it. thank you so much.

Comment: You have to just pass your latitude and longitude addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); here. and print in log like to see Log.v("address",addresses +"");

Answer (score 1):

```
  try {
        Geocoder geocoder;
        final List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        if (latitude != 0 || longitude != 0) {
         addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)));
       }
  catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    class GetLocationName extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    String result_str;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    public GetLocationName(double latitude,double longitude) {
        this.latitude=latitude;
        this.longitude=longitude;
    }

    /** hits and returns the location name JsonObject */
    public JSONObject getLocationInfo() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="
                        + latitude + "," + longitude
                        + "&sensor=true");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            int b;
            while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... args) {
        try {
                JSONObject ret = getLocationInfo();
                JSONObject location;
                String location_string;
                location = ret.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0);
                location_string = location.getString("formatted_address");
                result_str = location_string;
                Log.v("Selected", result_str);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            CurrentAddrStr = result_str;//this will have the address
        } else {
            //something went wrong..
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

just pass the latitude and longitude to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you need is the [`Geocoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html). A code example can be found [here](http://android-er.blogspot.be/2011/02/get-address-from-location-using.html).